Seeking Tools for Efficient Illustration Design in Physics Book Project
One of my friends intends to write a book related to the field of physics. I have been assigned to design illustrations similar to the images below for his book. The total number of these illustrations is about 150. I am familiar with tools like PowerPoint, Illustrator, and Photoshop. However, given the volume of work, I am looking for recommendations on tools that publishers use to increase efficiency and save time. If you know of any suitable tools for my work or have any experience in this area, please guide me...
First image
Second image
Third image

Experienced users are efficient with the tool of their choice. So what tool are you proficient with? Graphic design is a profession after all.

I am not a publisher and myself have a similar question, actually. But maybe my experience can be useful to you. I ended up not inventing a wheel and just have been doing all my drawings in AutoCAD. I.e., you don't have to use AutoCAD for technical drawings only. Schematics for papers or books can be done in it the same way we do technical drawings there. Actually, I have moved to LibreCAD since recently, because I prefer open source. And I am just curious why you are talking about PowerPoint, Illustrator and Photoshop. How do these tools can, possibly, come to mind?

Thank you for your suggestion, but that wasn't the answer to my question. @Jon Custer

Your example pictures are all optics drawings. For that context, as well as pulley diagrams etc., I've heard good things about a tool called EdrawMax, which has a lot of suitable templates to speed up the design work.

Thank you, my friend.
